# Firmware vs. ios

Tags: ios, firmware

I’m asking what the difference is cuz i’m having an iPad issue and there is an online company that offers services to fix an apple boot loop.
I downloaded the free trial and it had me download firmware 13.2.3 to fix issue. However, to get firmware to actually work to have to pay $40. 
I’m thinking what i probably really just downloaded was the updated iOS software and they want to charge me for something i can do for free using my Finder through Catalina and selecting “update” when trying to restore. Which, by the way, i already tried and it didn't work.
Am i right? Or is firmware something different?
Please advise....

Answer (score 3):

The service sounds sketchy. What is their sales site and policy for returns if you buy their service and it doesn’t work?

Apple provides firmware for free as well as tech support for basic things like restoring your iOS device and not needing to pay for any software, so I would start there if you’re not convinced the paid service is reputable or appropriate.

You only need Finder / Catalina and here is your step by step guide:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

There’s a link if the device does not show up when attached, and a link for more help at the bottom if you follow all the steps and still cannot load Apple [firmware and software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40554/ios-and-firmware-differences) on your iPad.